# Distribution over-the-air without providing UDID

Tags: ios

A couple of days ago I was asked whether it is possible to record a conversation using an iPhone. Having heard of Apple’s disapproval of that given function, I have confirmed it was not possible. However, out of curiosity, I have googled the info on this issue. Surprisingly, it led me to a website offering a variety of dubious shady activities (wiretapping related).

I will leave all the details behind, just to tell you in a few words that out of desire to understand how it was even possible, using that site I easily managed to install an unauthorized third-party application onto my iPhone with iOS 8.0 bypassing the legal distribution channels and without me providing them the UDID of my phone so they could add it to their distribute certificate (eventually substituting the original messenger app (WhatsApp, Skype, etc.) with their almost identical clone that is collecting and submitting personal info).

As far as i understood the clean/not jailbreaked iOS has no distribution channels  other than AppStore, Ad Hoc or Enterprise channels (with providing UDID in the latter two).

I don’t know if this is a system flaw or vulnerability, but this is supposed to not be possible. Maybe, though, my logic is missing something. That is why I am trying to address this issue here.

The aim of this post is to bring up your expertise and to find out collectively the mechanics of these activities to ultimately prompt Apple to eliminate the related shortcomings.

Again, I have the details and can provide them in case needed, but for the sake of not being deleted or, God forbid, banned I am keeping those to myself for the moment.

Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a question.  Interesting stuff if true, but this better belongs on a blog post than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The question in this post is - how is this even possible, given the Apple's claim that iOS is secure enough not to allow such stuff to happen. I can't add a screenshot with iOS offering to install app from untrusted source due to some mr.Do-Good putting a minus on my post and not enough rep as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can buy an [enterprise account for 299$ per year](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) to build in-house Apps, which can be distributed without knowing or adding any UDID.
These Apps should normally only be distributed to employees, but this restriction is often ignored and Apple bans those accounts then.